# Unable to setup RKHunter ("Invalid SCRIPTWHITELIST configuration option")

Tags: raspbian, networking, security

I installed RKHunter (rootkit hunter) on Raspbian Jessie using "apt-get install". Before that I performed apt-get update and upgrade as well as autoclean.

When setting up RKHunter, the first few steps are working. But then for some reason I can't check the current values and store them as known-good values using `sudo rkhunter --propupd`.

I get the message `Invalid SCRIPTWHITELIST configuration option: non-existent pathname: usr/bin/lwp-request`

Why am I getting this and how can I fix it please ?

I followed the following guide however I didn't install from sources but with apt-get:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rkhunter-to-guard-against-rootkits-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since nobody stepped up I continued searching and found a few things that I think can help answer this question for documentation's sake and future readers. **Use at your own risk.** 
If anyone has some insights or input as to the safety or logic of doing this please let us know.

**Potential answer/solution:** Based on the following links, it seems that it is possible and safe to comment out the offending elements out of the `/etc/rkhunter.conf` file.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=773974
http://www.itrig.de/index.php?/archives/2182-Rkhunter-Rootkit-Hunter-und-Chrootkit-auf-Ubuntu-installieren,-aktualisieren-und-konfigurieren.html ("Troubleshooting" part).

Will test it out and report back.

Comment: **Checking back to conclude:** commented out the option regarding `usr/bin/lwp-request` in `/etc/rkhunter.conf` as explained at https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=773974. It worked and now rkhunter executes normally. **Use at your own risk.**

Comment: Hi, for me, the paths were just different. Files which were supposed to be under /usr/bin were under /bin/ and the like.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old. All you need to do is change the `rkhunter.conf` lines 593-600 to reflect location of egrep, fgrep, etc. Here is what it looks like.

```
SCRIPTWHITELIST=/usr/bin/egrep
SCRIPTWHITELIST=/usr/bin/fgrep
SCRIPTWHITELIST=/usr/bin/which
SCRIPTWHITELIST=/usr/bin/ldd
#SCRIPTWHITELIST=/usr/bin/lwp-request
SCRIPTWHITELIST=/usr/sbin/adduser
#SCRIPTWHITELIST=/usr/sbin/prelink
#SCRIPTWHITELIST=/usr/sbin/unhide.rb
```

Comment: Thank you! Confirming in 2021, under Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS the offending files were egrep and freg, which actually live in /bin.

Answer (score 0):

getting this error is simple problem it mean in the /etc/rkhunter.conf there have a addisional command so u need the remove that rkhunter.conf file and replace it with new rkhunter.conf file from this link https://www.mediafire.com/file/ojtay83m4nwrroa/rkhunter.conf/file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).